# how to compare a substring from char array with some valid range?

Tags: c++

I have a char * which contains year and month lets say YYYYMM. How can I compare MM within the range of 01 to 12 ? Do I have to do atoi for the substring and do it or anything else exists?

Comment: In C++ it would generally be better to use or design a date object which could be constructed from various formats.

Answer (score 1):

If the first character of the month portion of the string is '0' the second must be between '1' and '9' inclusive to be valid. If the first character is '1' the second must be between '0' and '2' inclusive to be valid. Any other initial character is invalid.

**In code**

```
bool valid_month (const char * yyyymm) {
  return ((yyymm[4] == '0') && (yyymm[5] >= '1') && (yyymm[5] <= '9')) ||
         ((yyymm[4] == '1') && (yyymm[5] >= '0') && (yyymm[5] <= '2'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks to David and Lou. That was helpful!

Comment: Apart from typos and assumption of valid bounds this is the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do atoi() of the substring or you can simply compare the ASCII values. For example:

```
if (buf[4] == '0')
{
  // check buf[5] for values between '1' and '9'
}
else if (buf[4] == '1')
{
  // check buf[5] for values between '0' and '2'
}
else
{
  // error
}
```

Either way is acceptable. I guess it really depends on how you will eventually store the information (as int or string).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your char* variable is called "pstr" and is null terminated after the MM you can do:

```
int iMon = atoi(pstr + 4);
if ( (iMon >= 1) && (iMon <= 12) )
{
  // Month is valid
}
```

Comment: -1: This approach will say that `"20111Z"` and `"19999#"` are valid.